# PHP - Array to MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, while-loop

I'm trying to insert textbox-fields text into MySQL table row, using `while` loop.

Here is a part of the code: ($datetoday = 270313)

```
                        <?php 


        $i=0;
        while ($i < $row_Num) {
            ${'date_'.$i} = $_REQUEST["{'date_'.$i}"];
            ${'text_'.$i} = $_REQUEST["{'text_'.$i}"];
            ${'con_name_'.$i} = $_REQUEST["{'con_name_'.$i}"];
            ${'con_phone_'.$i} = $_REQUEST["{'con_phone_'.$i}"];

           $values= array(${'date_'.$i},${'text_'.$i},${'con_name_'.$i},${'con_phone_'.$i});
           print_r($values);
           $sql = "INSERT INTO data.$datetoday(`KEY,`DATE`,`COLOR`,`TEXT`,`CON_NAME`,`PHONE`) VALUES (`$i`,`$values[0]`,`FFFFFF`,`$values[1]`,`$values[2]`,`$values[3]`)";
           $result = mysql_query($sql,$link);
           if (!$result) {
            die ("Can't create table named $datetoday : " . mysql_error());
            }
           $i++;
           }


        ?>
```

The URL of the page is:

```
> http://localhost:5110/test.php?date_0=000000&text_0=QWERTY&con_name_0=iuytre&con_phone_0=0000000000&date_1=111111&text_1=ASDFGHJK&con_name_1=lkjhgfd&con_phone_1=1212121212
```

However it doesn't update the table or print the array (for testing). Any suggestions?

Comment: Localhost does not work for us :-) Furthermore you might want to get back to the basics of PHP. This is far from logical an simple what you are trying to do here. Also printr() is not a function (not by default -> print_r()). And why create variables to re-use them in a very weird way again..

Comment: Have you confirmed that `$row_Num` is greater than or equal to '1'? In other words are you certain you are getting in the `while` loop?

Comment: Thank you,
but I still don't understend why it doesnt work.
what need do be changed in the array part?

Comment: @Asok - Yes, Im sure.

Comment: what is $datetoday ? doesn't appear anywere before it is used

Comment: In your URL you are showing `date_0` and `date_1`. But in your loop you are starting at `date_1`, is this intended? Maybe you need to set `$i = 0;`??

Comment: @SirDarius - it is the date of today in form of ddmmyy - (270313).
it is the name of the table that created earlier in the code.

Comment: @Asok - it wasn't intended, Just fixed it.
but still the code doesn't work...

Comment: Also your printr is wrong, should be `print_r`

Comment: @Asok - thank you, now it prints the array but it is empty.
this code need to be activated after a button is pressed.
I wiil fix it soon and come back

Comment: @user2216190 See my answer below.

Comment: @user2216190 Did you get this resolved? If so, please either post your own answer and accept or accept the appropriate answer to close this quesiton.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were several minor things wrong, using your URL substring I got it working, see below:

```
$row_Num = 1;
$i = 0;
while ($i <= $row_Num) {
    // In the $_REQUEST you were indexing the curly braces, remove them.
    ${"date_" . $i} = $_REQUEST["date_$i"];
    ${"text_" . $i} = $_REQUEST["text_$i"];
    ${"con_name_" . $i} = $_REQUEST["con_name_$i"];
    ${"con_phone_" . $i} = $_REQUEST["con_phone_$i"];

    $values = array(
        ${"date_" . $i},
        ${"text_" . $i},
        ${"con_name_" . $i},
        ${"con_phone_" . $i}
    );
    // Not printr() And this is how I print arrays, it is cleaner.
    echo '<pre>', print_r($values, true), '</pre>';
    $i++;
}
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 000000
    [1] => QWERTY
    [2] => iuytre
    [3] => 0000000000
)
Array
(
    [0] => 111111
    [1] => ASDFGHJK
    [2] => lkjhgfd
    [3] => 1212121212
)
```

---

**Edit**

I am still not clear how you are setting `$row_Num`.

```
$_SESSION['row_Num'] = $_REQUEST["row_Num"];
```

This doesn't tell me anything since the `$_REQUEST` string you are showing doesn't contain "row_Num". So since your query requires `DATE` I made a `foreach` loop to count how many times `DATE` appears. Try the following code and let me know.

```
$i = 0;
$count = 0;
// I added this line to take care of how many times the loop runs
foreach ($_REQUEST as $key => $value) { (strstr($key, 'date')) ? $count++ : NULL; }
// Changed '<=' to '<' because it would loop 3 times since we start $i at 0.
// $i needs to remain at 0 since your URL substring indexing starts at 0.
while ($i < $count) {
    ${'date_' . $i} = $_REQUEST["date_$i"];
    ${'text_' . $i} = $_REQUEST["text_$i"];
    ${'con_name_' . $i} = $_REQUEST["con_name_$i"];
    ${'con_phone_' . $i} = $_REQUEST["con_phone_$i"];

    $values = array(
        ${"date_" . $i},
        ${"text_" . $i},
        ${"con_name_" . $i},
        ${"con_phone_" . $i}
    );

    ### Echo for troubleshooting ###
    echo '<pre>', print_r($values, true), '</pre>';
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `data`.`".$datetoday."` (`KEY`,`DATE`,`COLOR`,`TEXT`,`CON_NAME`,`PHONE`) VALUES 
        (
            '".$i."',
            '".$values[0]."',
            'FFFFFF',
            '".$values[1]."',
            '".$values[2]."',
            '".$values[3]."'
        )";

    ### Echo for troubleshooting ###
    echo '<pre>', $sql, '</pre>';
    $result = mysql_query($sql, $link) or die ('Could not insert values: '.mysql_error());
    $i++;
}
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 000000
    [1] => QWERTY
    [2] => iuytre
    [3] => 0000000000
)
INSERT INTO `data`.`280313` (`KEY`,`DATE`,`COLOR`,`TEXT`,`CON_NAME`,`PHONE`) VALUES 
        (
            '0',
            '000000',
            'FFFFFF',
            'QWERTY',
            'iuytre',
            '0000000000'
        )
Array
(
    [0] => 111111
    [1] => ASDFGHJK
    [2] => lkjhgfd
    [3] => 1212121212
)
INSERT INTO `data`.`280313` (`KEY`,`DATE`,`COLOR`,`TEXT`,`CON_NAME`,`PHONE`) VALUES 
        (
            '1',
            '111111',
            'FFFFFF',
            'ASDFGHJK',
            'lkjhgfd',
            '1212121212'
        )
```

Comment: Thank you for you'r solution-
but the code (the first one) prints only the 1st array.
EDIT - I think that the problem is with the $row_Num,cheking it now...

Comment: That's interesting, I was able to get both. How are you setting `$row_Num`?

Comment: I changed $row_Num into a session called "$_SESSION['row_Num']".
when I print $_SESSION['row_Num'] it shows the right value, but when I use it in the while-loop it doesn't work well..

Comment: Can you edit your question showing exactly how you are setting `$row_Num` or `$_SESSION['row_Num']` and can you explain a little more what you mean by "it doesn't work well". Sorry, I am a little confused.

Comment: As for the '1st MySQL row is updated', it may because you're inserting `$i` into the database in possibly an auto-incrementing field or a unique field. Verify that `KEY` doesn't need to be unique or can be set to '0', the first iteration of `$i` is 0

Comment: I meant that it doesn't do the right number of loops .
this is the statement for the table:
"CREATE TABLE data.$datetoday(
  `KEY` INT NOT NULL ,
  `DATE` DATETIME NOT NULL ,
  `COLOR` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `TEXT` TINYTEXT NULL ,
  `CON_NAME` TINYTEXT NULL ,
  `PHONE` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`KEY`))";

Comment: setting session:      session_start();
    $_SESSION['row_Num'] = $_REQUEST["row_Num"];

Answer (score 1):

Use `'date_' . $i` instead of `'date_'.'$i'`

`'date_'.'$i'` is always `date_$i`, no expansion of the variable `$i` is done due to the use of single quotes. If you want to expand variables inside strings, use double quotes (or no quotes if the $variables is at the start or end of the string).

Answer (score 0):

Note that call n times SQL request is slow. It will be better if you send one SQL request. Something like this:

```
<?php 
 $i=0;$comma="";$all_values="";
 while($i<$row_Num)
 {${'date_'.$i}=$_REQUEST["date_".$i];
  ${'text_'.$i}=$_REQUEST["text_".$i];
  ${'con_name_'.$i}=$_REQUEST["con_name_"$i];
  ${'con_phone_'.$i}=$_REQUEST["con_phone_".$i];

  $values=array(${'date_'.$i},${'text_'.$i},${'con_name_'.$i},${'con_phone_'.$i});
  print_r($values);
  $all_values.=$comma."('".$i."','".$values[0]."','FFFFFF','".$values[1]."','".$values[2]."','".$values[3]."')";
  $comma=",";
  $i++;
 }
 $sql="INSERT INTO data.$datetoday (`KEY,`DATE`,`COLOR`,`TEXT`,`CON_NAME`,`PHONE`) VALUES ".$all_values;
 $result=mysql_query($sql,$link);
 if(!$result)
     die("Can't create table named $datetoday : ".mysql_error());
?>
```